# cannot compare between listview sub item and remove duplicate vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim hTable As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
Dim duplicateList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
Dim itm As ListViewItem

For Each itm In ListView1.Items
    If hTable.ContainsKey(itm.Text) AndAlso 
       hTable.ContainsKey(itm.SubItems(1).Text) AndAlso
       hTable.ContainsKey(itm.SubItems(2).Text) AndAlso
       hTable.ContainsKey(itm.SubItems(3).Text) Then

        'duplicate
        duplicateList.Add(itm)
    Else
       hTable.Add(itm.Text, String.Empty)
    End If
Next

'remove duplicates
For Each itm In duplicateList
    ListView1.Items.Remove(itm)
Next
```

I want to compare 3 subitem in listview like this:

> Date_***_*___***Name****_*__*_*_**_Value
>
> 11/12/13_**__***llallala****_*__*_*_**_12334
>
> 11/12/13_**__***llallala****_*__*_*_**_12334
>
> 11/12/13_**__***ddsfvxcv****_*____**_16542
>
> 13/12/12_**__***ddsfvxcv****_*____**_12334
>
> 10/12/13_**__***owowewe****_*____**_23024

then normally it will remove first and second row because it is duplicate but now it cannot....
sry for bad english

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~UPDATED~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Dim hTable As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
    Dim duplicateList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each itm In ListView1.Items
        If hTable.ContainsKey(itm.Text) AndAlso hTable.ContainsKey(itm.SubItems(1).Text) AndAlso hTable.ContainsKey(itm.SubItems(2).Text) AndAlso hTable.ContainsKey(itm.SubItems(3).Text) Then 'duplicate
            duplicateList.Add(itm)
            duplicateList.Add(itm.SubItems(1))
            duplicateList.Add(itm.SubItems(2))
            duplicateList.Add(itm.SubItems(3))
        Else
            hTable.Add(itm.Text, String.Empty)
            hTable.Add(itm.SubItems(1).Text, String.Empty)
            hTable.Add(itm.SubItems(2).Text, String.Empty)
            hTable.Add(itm.SubItems(3).Text, String.Empty)
        End If
    Next
    'remove duplicates
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each itm In duplicateList
        ListView1.Items.Remove(itm)
    Next
```

I put the On error resume next so the problem "solve"

but now the code running unstable....

i means duplicate can delete but some non-duplicate it delete also.....

like:

----Date_***_*___***Name****_*__*_*_**_Value

1---11/12/13_**__***llallala****_*__*_*_**_12334

2---11/12/13_**__***llallala****_*__*_*_**_12999

3---11/12/13_**__***ddsfvxcv****_*____**_16542

4---13/12/12_**__***ddsfvxcv****_*____**_12334

5---10/12/13_**__***owowewe****_*____**_23024

it will remove line 2 although it is not same....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arraylist only contains object.  Either switch to a `List(Of ListViewItem)` or try `ListView1.Items.Remove(DirectCast(itm, ListViewItem))`

You might be better off building a list of unique items and repopulating the listview with that.  Since you only want to compare 2 columns to test for equality, a custom equalitycomparer would work here. Something like this might work:

```
    Dim hTable As List(Of ListViewItem) = (From lvi In ListView1.Items
                                   Let newlvi = DirectCast(lvi, ListViewItem)
                                   Select newlvi
                                   ).Distinct(New CompareLVI).ToList
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    ListView1.Items.AddRange(hTable.ToArray)

Public Class CompareLVI
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ListViewItem)

    Public Function Equals1(x As ListViewItem, y As ListViewItem) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ListViewItem).Equals
        Return x.Text = y.Text AndAlso x.SubItems(1).Text = y.SubItems(1).Text
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As ListViewItem) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ListViewItem).GetHashCode

        Return obj.Text.GetHashCode Xor obj.SubItems(1).Text.GetHashCode
    End Function
End Class
```

The LINQ expression creates a unique list of listviewitems.  the distinct method uses the custom comparer to reject any items that have the same values in the first 2 columns.

Comment: sry I write wrong....
I means it just compare between first column....so if the first column is same but second and third is different then it will remove wrong....
remove item code is working just the compare code not working

Comment: I added another suggestion